Should research on artificial consciousness be regulated?
With the advancement of a series of AI technologies, including ChatGPT and o3, it appears that the realization of Artificial General Intelligence (AGI) is imminent. Consequently, it might be time to consider the relationship between AI and humans. From a human perspective, the optimal role for AI would be as an unconscious tool to enhance our productivity, much like steam engines, electric motors in traditional industries, and computers in the information age.
Therefore, a natural question arises: Should we regulate research on consciousness within the field of artificial intelligence? This could be one of the most direct ways to prevent potential future scenarios where AI might lead to human extinction.

Regarding whether AI should merely serve as a tool, a recent paper discusses this issue:
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0020174X.2024.243693
Why AGI could not be (just) a tool: goals, life, and general intelligence

It is widely believed that AGI has the potential to be a wonderful tool that humans can use to meet our needs, solve our problems, and improve our lives. Against this view, we argue that any entity with truly general, human-level intelligence would have the capacity to lead its own life, with its own purposes and integrated hierarchy of goals. And thus any true AGI could not be merely a tool, even if it turned out to be extremely helpful for human beings. If we are correct, there is a dilemma at the heart of the ambition to build AGI as a valuable tool. On the one hand, any mere tool that we might build would lack capacities essential to the kind of general intelligence exhibited by human beings; it would not be genuine AGI. On the other hand, were we to create genuine AGI, then what we would have created would not be a mere tool, but something more. In this paper, we make the case for this dilemma. In so doing, we illuminate the connections between a set of core ideas: intelligence, agency, tools, and life.

I hope this information is useful to you.
